# Why doesn't the C# Properties.settings.default.key read the updated value after a Properties.Settings.Default.save()?

Tags: c#, properties-file, settings

In the application (c# console app) settings file I have:
Key = "", with scope as User.

I then have the following code:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Key = "value1";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

string k = Properties.Settings.Default.Key; // here, k is an empty string.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: See if using Properties.Settings.Default.Reload() after the Save helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is persisting the settings and accessing the settings code executed in same user context? Lets say if the persisting code executed with administrative privilege(Impersonate) then it may behave differently.